# Copying Korean characters from Excel to TextEdit with AppleScript

Tags: excel, macos, encoding, utf-8, applescript

I have an Excel spreadsheet which contains Korean characters in who-knows-what encoding -- I'm assuming it's UTF-8 since I can copy and paste it into vim or textedit or whatever just fine.  I can then insert those characters into a database I know is UTF-8 and that works
just fine too.

However, when I run the following AppleScript that presumably does the same thing, I get all the Korean characters replaced by the letter "a".  Is there a way to force an encoding when copying or pasting with AppleScript?  Am I missing something else?

**Example cell in Korean: 이메일 주소.

Same output in TextEdit: aaa aa**

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
       activate
       open (choose file)
       activate object sheet "Sheet1"
       copy range range "A1:G1000" of active sheet
end tell

tell application "TextEdit"
       activate
       open (choose file)
       tell application "System Events"
               keystroke (the clipboard)
       end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are copying and pasting, why not just do that. You copy in excel so in TextEdit just use this...

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "v" using command down
end tell
```

Comment: for some reason that doesn't work, and i've tried. however i suspect if it did work, i'd still see the korean characters replaced with "a"s.

Comment: I tried it and it did work. Try 2 things, 1) remove the system events code from the text edit code (there's no reason to embed them together). 2) add a delay of 0.5 seconds just before the system events code.